# Find and replace text causes error in VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro created by Ron de Bruin, which I have modified to replace text in the files I open.

I use the code to open several files, grab the data, and switch the filtered column text "To Be Paid" to "Paid".

The problem I am having, is if the text is not found, (No records with this filter) the codes stops and does not complete.

Is there code that I can use to continue/skip this file and move on to the next one?

```
'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("List1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
    "<>"
Columns("J:J").Select
Selection.Replace What:="to be paid", Replacement:="paid", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   'Remove the AutoFilter
    .AutoFilterMode = False
            End With
        End If
        'Close the workbook without saving
        mybook.Close savechanges:=True
```

Comment: Before: `On Error Resume Next` and after `On Error Goto 0`? Or `If Not Columns("J:J") Is Nothing Then`

Answer (score 0):

You can Cheack if there are any Cells with "to be Paid" and do the Replacement if he had found one.

```
Dim FoundRange As Range   

  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("List1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
    "<>"
Columns("J:J").Select

Set FoundRange = Selection.Find(what:="to be paid", LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole)
if Not FoundRange is Nothing then
Selection.Replace What:="to be paid", Replacement:="paid", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End if

   'Remove the AutoFilter
    .AutoFilterMode = False
            End With
        End If
        'Close the workbook without saving
        mybook.Close savechanges:=True
```